# Why does the console print an object in an array but not an object

Tags: javascript

I have the following:

```
var allItems = {Items: [
                        {Value: 1, Name: "String1"},
                        {Value: 2, Name: "String2"},
                        {Value: 3, Name: "String3"}
                       ] 
               };

localStorage.setItem('allItems', allItems);
```

I'm struggling to access any properties of `allItems` after retrieving it from localStorage. How would I say access the Name of the second object in the array Items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use JSON [`stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to store the object and then use [`parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to convert it back into a JSON object.

```
localStorage.setItem('allItems', JSON.stringify(allItems));
var storageItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('allItems'));
console.log(storageItems.Items[1].Name);
```

Comment: Waaah. I knew there was a good reason. Hairline saved.